# Any way to disable FAQ page header for user with no cookies

Tags: feature-request, header

My Firefox is set up to erase cookies on exit. At the same time, I have created a address bar shortcut so that, for example, when I type "so python com" and press Enter in the address bar, Stack Overflow is opened with "python com" as the search string.

The presence of the FAQ first time user header is annoying.

Maybe support for a URL parameter like `&faq_header=0` could be added?

Comment: You could use a combination of platypus and greasemonkey to modify the page to your liking...

Comment: +1 timely: I was thinking of asking this question myself.  I'd go further: should the FAQ header even be there for visitors who reject cookies?  It's bound to be annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already run adblock you can also run [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4364) which lets you pick css items to block as well.

Comment: It's a fine workaround, but it doesn't solve the broader usability issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim**: SO&co should not be serving up the FAQ header to visitors who block cookies, even though workarounds exist.

**Reason**: It is bound to be annoying, and while SO and many its sibling sites are aimed at the tech savvy, many are not.  As a general point of usability, it is bad, and so should be stopped.

**Further thought**: We might still want to put a piece of text at the top of the page referring to the FAQ, since we do want new users of the site to look at it, but it should be less ... aggressive.